# Repetition using switch statement inside a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement, cs50

I am trying to use a loop to print out a repetitive song, "this old man"
The first verse is:
This old man, he played *one*
He played knick-knack on my *thumb*
This old man came rolling home

This song repeats to ten, varying the two terms in italicize
one -> two++ and thumb -> another item such as shoe, knee, etc.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string change1 (int i);
int main (void)
{ 
    for (int i = 1; ; 1 < 11; i++)
    {
        printf ("This old man, he played "); 
        change1(i);
        printf("He played knick-knack on my %s\n\n", s1);
    }

    return 0;
 }

string change1(int i)
{
    string s1;

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            printf("one\n");
            s1 = "thumb";
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            printf("two\n");
            s1 = "shoe";
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
            printf("ill add these cases later");
    }
}
```

This gives me an error message of: "control reaches end of non-void function"

---

I also got an undeclared variable s1 error but I declared it in the function.

Comment: There is no return at the end of `change1()`.

Comment: `change1` is declared to return a string, but it has no `return` statement to do so. And your `main` function never declares or assigns `s1`.

Comment: your for loop is a bit screwed as given, its not doing a comparison against i, and has an extra ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ variables have *scope*. A variable is generally visible inside the curly braces where it is declared; outside these brackets the variable does not exist.

That is why you cannot use `s1` from `change1` inside the loop: you need to return a value (best choice in your situation), or use a variable that is in scope in both `change1` and `main`.

```
printf ("This old man, he played ");
printf("He played knick-knack on my %s\n\n", change1(i));
...
string change1 (int i) {
    string s1;
    switch (i) {
        ...
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Note that you do not need a switch statement to implement `change1`: when the code is so uniform, you may be better off with an array:

```
const char *strings[] = {"thumb", "shoe", ...};
```

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey That's strange - he's using `string`, where would that come from? He may have mis-tagged the question, but them he may have also made a mistake with the code sample.

Comment: I guess you can never trust a tag... they're just like the statement of work I suppose... sometimes meaningless, sometimes misleading...

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post on here but I am working in C.
I got rid of the .c_str()) part and the .c compiled and worked just like it was supposed to. 
Is that bit of code C++?

Comment: Thank you! This worked out perfectly. 
I was using return 0;
What is the logic here? I understand scope and I was aware that anything outside of the {} would have to be initialized either globally or as a pointer but why return s1, not 0? 
Sorry, beginners question.

Comment: @dannylee `return` statement takes an expression. The value of that expression gets plugged in at the calling site in place of the invocation. In this example, the value of `s1` is plugged in in place of `change1(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your program to an actual C program, rather than C++

```
int main (void)
{
    int i;
    char* items[] = {"thumb", "shoe", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    char* numbers[] = {"one", "two", "three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf ("This old man, he played %s\n", numbers[i]);    
        printf("He played knick-knack on my %s\n\n", items[i]);
    }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: Very clean.  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

`change1` needs to return the string it decided on. And `main` has to assign the return value to a variable, because as originally written `s1` is local to the `change1` function.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string change1 (int i);
int main (void)
{ 
    for (int i = 1; ; 1 < 11; i++)
        {
            printf ("This old man, he played ");
            string s1 = change1(i);
            printf("He played knick-knack on my %s\n\n", s1);
        }
    return 0;
}

string change1 (int i)
{
    string s1;

    switch (i)
        {
        case 1: 
            {
                printf("one\n");
                s1 = "thumb";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                printf("two\n");
                s1 = "shoe";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
            printf("ill add these cases later");
        }
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Is `string` a `typedef`ed `char *`?

Comment: I saw `string` and I assumed it was C++, I didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score -1):

use return statement at the end of switch class

```
return s1;
```